# Can we follow multiple design patterns in one application

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

I am just learning design patterns and I have few questions

1) Can I have multiple design patterns in the application?

2) What are good or advised design patterns for ASP.NET B2C applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Design patterns is used to solve specific programming problems. They are not used to architecture your applications.

> 1) Can I have multiple design patterns in the application?

Yes. See above.

> 2) What are good or advised design patterns for ASP.NET B2C applications?

Guess you are asking if there are any existing frameworks available to create a website which is easy to extend and maintain?

Use [layered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) where you isolate each layer by using the [Separated Interface](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html) pattern. For the database, use [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) (easiest way to archive that is to use a ORM like [nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)). As for the webSite, use [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3).